# Delete a node from a linked list after finding it

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, nodes

I'm having trouble deleting a node from a linked list by inputting the telephone number of the record. This is the code that is supposed to do this:

```
typedef struct record
{   
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char telephone[20];
}Record;

typedef struct node
{
    Record data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

Node *head = NULL;

void delete() { 
    Node *n = head; 
    Node* previous = NULL;
    Node *next = n;
```

.
.
. (here i wrote the code to enter the number (stored in telNumber[20])and find the record containing the number

```
while (n != NULL) {
            if (&n->data.telephone == telNumber) {
                if (previous == NULL) {
                    n = n->next;
                    free(head);
                }
                else {
                    previous->next = n->next;
                    free(n);
                    n = previous->next;
                }
            }
            else {
                previous = n;
                n = n->next;
            }
        }
        printf("You have successfully deleted the telephone record");
```

The record still remains there.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (&n->data.telephone == telNumber)
```

is not how to compare strings for equality in C. That will compare the addresses, which will never match.

It should be:

```
if (strcmp(n->data.telephone, telNumber) == 0)
```

Comment: That did solve part of the problem, thanks. However, when displaying the records, the record is still there. Maybe i need to return something?